# input type file capture camera restrict viewport

Tags: javascript, html

trying to restrict camera capture, when I click on input button what I see is [camera without frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OOoX6.jpg) what I would like to see is [camera with frame and custom text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KRV8r.jpg)

Comment: doubt it could happen with webpage.

Answer (score 0):

The <s>dropped from specs</s> ([*actually it's coming back from the deads*](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-media-capture/)) `<input>` `capture` uses the OS' camera input.

Since it's like an normal File picker, you have no way to access it before it is sent to you by the user.

To do what you want, you must use the [getUserMedia API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getUserMedia), which is still not supported in Safari...

```js
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({video: true})
  .then(stream => {
    vid.srcObject = stream;
    vid.play();
    });
vid.onloadedmetadata = e => {
  overlay.style.left = (vid.videoWidth / 2 - 150) + 'px';
  overlay.style.top = (vid.videoHeight / 2 - 75) + 'px';
  };
```

```css
#overlay{
  border: 1px solid white;
  background: rgba(255,255,255,.5);
  position: absolute;
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
  }
```

```html
<video id="vid" autoplay></video>
<div id="overlay"></div>
```

As a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wvmz5w9f/) for chrome.